# Creating a text based game and I'm stuck

Tags: java

Currently in the game, it asks certain questions like, have you collected all the keys, killed all the bosses etc.
But when it gets closes to the ending and it asks "Which key would you like to use?". It does that fine, but once it get to the Door section, it doesn't actually get the value of the key, it just outputs 0

Main piece of code

```
public static int possibleKey()
{            
    SetnGet sng = new SetnGet();
    int keys;
    do
    {   
        System.out.println("Which key would you like to use?");
        keys = in.nextInt();
         }
     while(keys != 1 && keys != 2 && keys != 3);

    return keys;
}

public static int possibleLevel()
{
    SetnGet sng = new SetnGet();
    System.out.println("Which door would you like to enter? - 1, 2, 3 or 4");
    int level;  

    if(sng.accessibleKey() == 3)
    {
        do
        {   
            System.out.println("You have all three keys, you have complete access");
            level = in.nextInt();
        }
        while(level != 1 && level != 2 && level != 3);
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {   
            System.out.println("You have no level access");
            level = in.nextInt();
        }
        while(level != 1 && level != 2 && level != 3 && level != 4);

    }
    return level;
}
```

The set and get from the SetnGet Class

```
private int possibleKey;
private int possibleLevel;

public int setPossibleKey()
{
    return possibleKey;
}

public void setPossibleKey(int possibleKey)
{
    this.possibleKey = possibleKey;
}

public int getPossibleLevel()
{
    return possibleLevel;
}

public void setPossibleLevel(int possibleLevel)
{
    this.possibleLevel = possibleLevel;
}
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in your IDE debugger?  What did you find?

Comment: I found out that once running through the IDE debugger each time to test each bits of data. It is going from sng.accessibleKey to System.out.println("You have no level access");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `possibleLevel()` creates an instance of the `SetnGet` class (`SetnGet sng = new SetnGet();`) and, right after that, reads the field of type `int` of the instance (`sng.accessibleKey()`). The result of such read is of course 0, because this is the default value of `int` class fields and you never set any other value to your field. As a result you always go to `else` and see the "You have no level access" message.

What you *could* do to fix the problem is to move `SetnGet sng = new SetnGet();` from `possibleLevel()` to the class and then make sure that the result of `possibleKey()` call is set to it, something like this:

```
public class Main {

    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static SetnGet sng = new SetnGet();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int selectedKey = possibleKey();
        sng.accessibleKey(selectedKey);
        int level = possibleLevel();
    }

    public static int possibleKey() {
        // your initial implementation of the method
    }

    public static int possibleLevel() {
        // your initial implementation of the method, but
        // without the "SetnGet sng = new SetnGet();" line
    }
}
```

Where the `SetnGet` class looks like this:

```
class SetnGet {

    private int accessibleKey;

    int accessibleKey() {
        return accessibleKey;
    }

    void accessibleKey(int accessibleKey) {
        this.accessibleKey = accessibleKey;
    }
}
```

This will fix your initial problem. Then you can consider further refactoring of the code, for example, using method arguments (instead of shared class fields) to pass data between methods, get rid of the redundant `SetnGet sng = new SetnGet();` line from the `possibleKey()` method as well, etc.